# Gnuplot: fence plot from data

Tags: gnuplot, fence-plots

I'm trying to figure out how to do fence plots in gnuplot, but I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on in the examples I find on the internet.

I have a (varying) number of data sets from different points in time in my simulation, in a datafile organized as a matrix of values<sup>1</sup>:

```
t1    x11    y11   // indices here indicate that (x1,y1) are a data point which
t1    x21    y21   // I'd plot on a regular 2D plot for this timestep, with the
...                // additional index noting which time step the values are for.
t1    xN1    yN1   
[blank line]
t2    x12    y12
t2    x22    y22
...
t2    xN2    yN2
[etc...]
tM    xNM    yNM
```

I want to plot this with one fence for each time value. I can plot do simply `splot 'data.txt'` and get something which is quite similar to what I want - `+` markers along the "top edges" of the fences, with time on x axis, x-data on y axis and y-data on z axis. However, if I add something like `w lines` to the `splot` command I just get a surface with all the data series connected.

I've tried to adapt the examples from [the demo script collection](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/surface1.html) (about halfway down), but they both rely on a dummy variable, and I can't figure out how to combine that with my data series. I've found some other exampels as well, but they are all quite elaborate and I don't understand what they do at all.

What is a good way to create fence plots from data using gnuplot?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> If it's necessary, it is possible to change this - I am in control of the code that generates the data. It's a hassle, though...</sup>

Comment: `<sup>something</sup>` -- I need to remember that one ...

Comment: @mgilson: It's easy to remember if you know that it's short for *superscript*. Can you guess what `<sub>something</sub>` does? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does require a bit of a change to the data unfortunately.  The change is pretty minor though and could probably be handled with a simple `awk`<sup>1,2</sup> script:

Here's a copy/paste of my interactive gnuplot session:

```
gnuplot> !cat test.dat
1 2 3
1 2 0

1 3 4
1 3 0

1 4 5
1 4 0


2 2 3
2 2 0

2 3 4
2 3 0

2 4 5
2 4 0


3 2 3
3 2 0

3 3 4
3 3 0

3 4 5
3 4 0
!
gnuplot> splot 'test.dat' u 1:2:3 w lines
```

The thing to note here is that there are 2 blank lines between "fences" and each x,y data point appears twice with a blank line afterward.  The second time it appears, the z-coordinate is 0.

To get each fence to have a different color:

```
gnuplot> splot for [i=0:3] 'test.dat' index i u 1:2:3 w lines
```

The awk script can even be done inline:

```
splot "< awk {...} datafile"
```

But that can get a little tricky with quoting (to include a single quote in a single quoted string, you double it) ...

```
AWKCMD='awk ''{if(!NF){print ""}else if(index($0,"#")!=1){printf "%s %s %s\n%s %s 0\n\n", $1,$2,$3,$1,$2}}'' '
splot '<'.AWKCMD.'datafile.dat' u 1:2:3 w lines
```

As far as efficiency is concerned, I'm believe that the iteration I used above will call the awk command for each time it iterates.  The workaround here is to pull the color from the index number:

```
splot '<'.AWKCMD.' test.dat' u 1:2:3:(column(-2)) w l lc variable
```

I believe that this will only do the `awk` command once as desired so with only a million entries it should still respond relatively quickly.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>`awk '{if(!NF){print ""}else{printf "%s %s %s\n%s %s 0\n\n", $1,$2,$3,$1,$2}}' test.dat`</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>`awk '{if(!NF){print ""}else if(index($0,"#")!=1){printf "%s %s %s\n%s %s 0\n\n", $1,$2,$3,$1,$2}}' test.dat` (version which ignores comments)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! A few follow-up questions: 1) I've never used `awk` before. How do I modify this to ignore all lines that start with `#`? I use that to print out diagnostic output in my data file (some information about the run, for future reference), and I'd like to keep that intact. 2) Is this performance-heavy? One data file usually contains ~10^5-10^6 lines of data. 3) If I'm not mistaken, it's possible to do this directly in the gnuplot script, instead of having two separate steps. How do I do that? Thanks again!

Comment: Brilliant! Just like that - it gives me beauty! I'll have to play around a little with transparency etc to make it even better, but that's another matter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, I should add: the data file I tested this on had 10 000 lines, and it ran in milliseconds (not enough for me to notice a delay). Big data files are no problem with this approach - at least not with the do-it-all-inside-gnuplot version. Thanks again!