# Gnuplot - Trying to create a waterfall/ fence plot

Tags: gnuplot, fence-plots

I try to create a nice waterfall map with gnuplot showing the development of an optical spectrum with current. My goal is to achieve something close to this :

[A waterfall plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vdcc.png)

I have tried this command

```
splot [][1160:1200][-80:-30] "Waterfall.txt" u 1:2:3 w l lw 3 lc rgb 'black'
```

The "Waterfall.txt" file has the format suggested in the accepted answer here [Gnuplot: fence plot from data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018524/gnuplot-fence-plot-from-data).
I have ignored z-data values lower than -80, substituting them with NaN.

The outcome is shown in the next image link.

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72x9v.png)

As you can see, compared with the previous figure, this is confusing to the reader. How can I fix it in order for it to be close to the first image and thus more clear to the viewer ?

Edit:

Thanks to @Ethan's answer it worked. The outcome is shown in the figure below. The only problem is the transparency of each fence, that reveals partially the subsequent fences.

[The new attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePtQz.png)

Comment: Since version 5.2 you can use `zerrorfill` for fence plots, see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/fenceplot.html

Comment: It is not clear from your description how you replaced some of the values with NaN, but this is probably a bad idea.  It is likely the cause of the disconnected line fragments in the plot you show, since gnuplot does not connect two points in a data set that have intervening NaN values. If the NaN values are already in the data file, you may be able to recover by using the gnuplot command `set datafile missing NaN`. As Christophe says, the current recommended way to construct a fence plot is to use the `zerrorfill` plotting style.  Please try that and amend your question if it does not work.

Comment: @Ethan can you shortly explain how to use the zerrorfill ? 

I have twenty 2D files with the YZ (Y = Wavelength, Z = Power) data. Each 2D file corresponds to a X value ( X = Current). I have used MATLAB to open these files and format the data to a txt file in the manner similar to the accepted answer I posted earlier. The range of z values is from -120 to -30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume twenty 2D files each containing Y and Z:

Gnuplot version 5.2

```
  filename(i) = 'silver.dat'
  set pm3d scansauto
  set style fill solid noborder
  set xyplane at 0
  set log z
  unset key
  splot for [k=20:1:-1] filename(k) using 1:(k):2:(1.0):2 with zerrorfill \
        fc "white" lc "black" lw 2
```

- I don't have your data files so I use the same file 20 times for the purpose of illustration.  It is based on the zerror demo in the gnuplot distribution and online demo set.
- Note that the base of each 'fence' is set to (z=1.0) rather than zero because of the log scale on z.
- The figure shown was made using a newer gnuplot. It uses partial transparency and a fancier bounding box that isn't in 5.2
  [image]

Comment: Thank you @Ethan for your answer. I try to implement it but I have a problem. I use :
  splot for [I=440:-20:100] sprintf("Bifurcation_SLV_LASER_Tslave=21_Vabs50_OSA_TRACES_FULL_Imst=0_Islv=%.2f_Pinj=0.00",I) using (I):1:2:(-120):2 with zerrorfill \
      fc "white" lc "black" lw 2 . But I get " Warning: empty x range [440:440], adjusting to [435.6:444.4] " and no plot.

Comment: The form of an iteration is `for [i=start:end:increment]`.   I think your pot command should have been `splot for [440:100:-20]...`.